# elasticsearch issue- i working with comand curl -X GET "localhost:9200" ,not working 4 curl -X GET "public_ipv4_of_ubuntu_server:9200"

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQiAQ.png)Hi am trying to configure elastic search on ubuntu 16.04 and was able to install it correctly along with Java.

and when i run the command on ubuntu terminal curl -X GET "localhost:9200" it is working fine and i can see the result as expected.

However, when i try to run the command on same terminal: curl -X GET "public_ipv4_of_ubuntu_server:9200", it is throwing error "Connection refused"

I was able to do this in centos server but in ubuntu i am getting this error.

network.host: 0.0.0.0

i have tried many of the avialable solutions but none of them are working. can you please help me out to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you're entering `0.0.0.0` as host it only will be accessible via `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` or loopback address.

If you want it to be accessible by any other IP you should configure in `elasticsearch.yml`

`http.publish_host` or `network.host` to a public IP of the server. Don't forget to restart Elasticsearch

More information on this - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html

Comment: when i tried like below-network.host: public_ip_ubuntu_server, it is showing error in logs as-Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address

Comment: The result of elasticsearch status is below-                                                                    root@ip-xx-xx-xx-x:/# sudo service elasticsearch status
? elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-01-19 16:16:59 UTC; 5s ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
 Main PID: 4990 (java)
    Tasks: 19
   Memory: 321.4M
      CPU: 11.014s
   CGroup: /system.slice/elasticsearch.service
           +-4990 /usr/bin/java -Xms200m -Xmx500m -XX:+U

Comment: public_ip_ubuntu_server I hope you assign proper ip there, right? not the string?

Comment: it is not string. example -> network.host: 123.31.2.2

Comment: could you run netstat -a -n | grep "LIST" ? to check if this port isn't occupied by some other program?

Comment: I cannot see port listed here:9200

Comment: could you run ifconfig -a and see your desired IP?

Comment: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN

Comment: it's ens5 mentioning my private_ipv4_addr in "inet" field.

Comment: :/# netstat -a -n | grep "LIST"
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::9200                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::9300                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN

Comment: any solution. i have setup network.host: 0, when i doing curl -X GET "privat_ip:9200" it is running fine but from my browser of my local machine i cannot connect to same. and also curl -X "public_ip_ubuntuserver:9200" gives connection time out. Please help me here.